# How can I only make a specific screen sleep?

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, screen, standby

I use my laptop with multiscreen: laptop screen on one side, my TV displaying my media center (Kodi) on the other side. Problem, when I use my media center to watch a movie, the laptop screen never switch to sleep mode.

I'm looking for a command to sleep the laptop screen, but ONLY this screen, and go out of this mode by using the touchpad. I was thinking to use xrandr, but it seems I can only deactivate (with option `--off`) the screen, and not just *sleep* it.

Any idea that would help?

Comment: you can simply dim the screen to zero, would that do?

Comment: Hi user3166173 posted my answer. Please mention if you manage (or not).

Answer (score 3):

#### Toggle- dim a specific screen

The command to *dim* the screen (not switch off, but not "sleep" either) would be:

```bsh
xrandr --output $monitor --brightness 0
```

You can however easily toggle- dim the targeted screen with a keyboard shortcut. Add the script below to a shortcut:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# --- set your monitor below
monitor=VGA-0
# ---
if [ -z "$(xrandr --verbose | grep 'Brightness: 0.0')" ]; then
  xrandr --output $monitor --brightness 0
else
  xrandr --output $monitor --brightness 1
fi
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `dim_screen.sh`, and *make it executable*
- In the head of the script, set the name of your targeted screen. Run the command `xrandr` to find out if you don't know.
- Add it to a shortut key: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```bsh
    /path/to/dim_screen.sh
```

### Explanation

The test:

```bsh
[ -z "$(xrandr --verbose | grep 'Brightness: 0.0')" ]
```

will see if the command `xrandr --verbose | grep 'Brightness: 0.0'` has an output, in other words, if your screen is dimmed. If so, it will set the targeted screen to "normal" brightness (1.0):

```bsh
xrandr --output $monitor --brightness 1
```

...else it will dim the screen with the command:

```
xrandr --output $monitor --brightness 0
```

#### Note

It seems impossible to only put a specific screen to *sleep*. This answer is written, assuming you want the screen, *dimmed*, but switching it off, including the black out of both screens, is too much a fuzz.

Comment: This answer worked great for me with one exception. In Ubuntu 16.04 I can’t seem to use “/path/to/dim_screen.sh” to create a shortcut key. I had to put the script in the search path and use just “dim_screen.sh” to make it work but work it does. +1

Comment: Hi! In fact FN+F6 is exactly what I need, but I have read that it is purely hardware so it seems that we can't use an equivalent command in shell, or we can't simulate the FN key to reproduce it in a script. For the moment, your response is the closest solution I have found. I have also improved it (accordfing to my needs) by using the command xbacklight after your xrandr command:
  `xbacklight -set 0`

Comment: @user3166173   If you'd really want it time- and touchpad triggered, it can be done. It would require a background process though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't see what you mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: @user3166173 in your original question, you mention waking up by touchpad event.

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I turn off the backlight but leave the LCD on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137854/how-do-i-turn-off-the-backlight-but-leave-the-lcd-on):

```bash
$ sudo -i
# Turn backlight off
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
# Turn backlight on
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power
exit
$
```

I've just tried this and it works fine on my laptop.